# magento v1.9 catalog price rules doesn't work some times

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, catalog-price-rules, promotions, ce-1.9.2.3

We are using Magento version 1.9.2.3. We have cart price rules setup based on user's group and product's custom attribute. It sometimes doesn't work. And I am not sure what the reason is. I can't really replicate the issue as it is on and off type of issue.

Users are complaining about it for not getting discounts and i can verify it form their order but if i manually add same order for the specific user then i see the discount.

Has any one experienced this issue. I will really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Did you found solution ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento, I have applied your solution but today we found same issues that products with this condition is not working at all

"If ALL of these conditions are TRUE:
Product Tag contains abc

Comment: is other catalog price rules are not working ? or only condition : `If ALL of these conditions are TRUE: Product Tag contains abc ` is not working ?

Comment: However, i have the cron job running but it fixed the issue i guess temporarily when i went to the specific promotion and then click on save button

Comment: there may be lot other reasons, google is your friend. even i had this problem i struggled a lot to solve this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catalog price rules Need Cron jobs.  install this [extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html) and check whether cron is working or not. 
if it is working check your Default Store Timezone is matching your server timezone.

[image]

credits : **@Alexei Yerofeyev**

if both timings are same, than Yes, this is a bug in Magento (or some logic beyond my understanding). we had the same problem. When Magento displays products on frontend, it checks if there are catalog rules for this date. And the date used for this check is your local, so in our case it was GMT+5. However, when catalog rules are being applied, it uses GMT date. So that means that we were't able to apply rules until 5 AM.

The problem is in **Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Action_Index_Refresh::execute()** function. You will have to rewrite this function/class either in your extension, or via the local version of the file.

we replaced line 121:

```
$timestamp = $coreDate->gmtTimestamp('Today');
```

with this line:

```
$timestamp = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date(null, null, null, true)->get(Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP);
```

After that it worked for us.

if that also didt worked for you, than

using AOE scheduler extension, change `catalogrule_apply_all` cron expression from `0 1 * * *` to `30 */6 * * *` and it may work for you.

if possible check the order time that didt applied discount and you may need to find what is exact timings that price rules are not working. Temparary fix is clicking "Apply catalog rules " button again when it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that Catalog Price Rules require cron to work flawlessly. If there're issues with cron (not running, crashing, so on), those rules stop working automatically. This might sound like a weird design decision, but when something goes south people usually prefer to to have rules deactivated too early rather than too late.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is not cron. Issue is it is working for some price and not working for some price. I mean not exactly 50% discount for all products. Specific clearance items.

Answer (score 0):

Check your cron - is it running properly? 
View cron_schedule database table for entries "catalogrule_apply_all" and see their status.

Try to apply manually catalog rule and check again.